# Lost token when passing req to jwt validator function. with .all() function

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

```
var category = require('../controllers/category/category.controller')
var _verifyToken = require('../../config/verify_jwt_token')
var prefix = '/category'
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.route(prefix + '/categories').all(_verifyToken.verifyToken).get(category.getAllCategories)
}
```

x-access-token header is available in **getAllcategories** *get(category.getAllCategories)*
     controller but when I pass request to the *.all(_verifyToken.verifyToken)*  function. I lost the token.

```
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
      'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
    )
    res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'X-Requested-With, content-type, x-access-token, Authorization'
    )
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', false)
    next()
  })
```

That is only happening with  Angular 6. With postman and angularJS 1, it is working fine

**Angular Token interceptor**

```
constructor( private _authService: AuthService) {}
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>  {
    // let authService:
    console.log('Here is the token interceptor');
    // const token = this._authService.getToken();
    // console.log(token);
    const tokenizedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json"',
        'x-access-token': `${this._authService.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
  }
```

**Angular Request**

```
_getAllCategoriesUrl = environment.APIEndPoint + '/category/categories';
  getCategories() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this._getAllCategoriesUrl);
  }
```

Comment: I didn't quite understood your question, but i think similar behavior can be achieved by just splitting routes and defining a middlewares for group of them directly. Example: https://pastebin.com/T6m1zsTb

Comment: problem - when i remove .all(_verifyToken.verifyToken) and console.log(req.headers) in getAllgategories x-access-token available there. but in verifyToken i do console.log(req.headers) x-access-token is undefined

Comment: I found the solution... It happened because of preflight request.